# how to change editor behavior in intellij idea

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, sublimetext, vi, ideavim

I have installed IntelliJIdea 14.0.2 just now. I do not know its default editor but it is opening my source files in `vi` option now. So, not letting me do default action like `Ctrl + v`, `Ctrl + d` which was present before and I used to like it.

So, how to change this behavior like present in `sublime - editors`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you don't need vi keybindings, uninstall the IdeaVIM plugin.

Comment: Thanks. All I wanted was not to mess again with my IDE environment settings again. Uninstalled IdeaVIM and once again my IDE is back in right place. :)

Answer (score 126):

disable below option in menu bar.

Tools -> VimEmulator(Ctrl + Alt + V)

Comment: Except for vi haters, this is the best answer. 90% of the time, I want to be in vi mode. There are just those times when...

Comment: This just saved me! I inadvertently disabled vim mode and couldn't figure it out. Re-installing the plugin didn't work nor did anything else until I saw this answer. tyvm!!!!

Comment: Cool, just added a shortcut for this, and it's to switch back and forth. Particularly if you want to use multicursor mode for a while.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I don't want to get rid of the VI Emulator completely

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! It's great when we're pairing, and some people prefer vi, others not so much. :)

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to uninstall vi, you can either turn it off, like @redredtokki states (Tools > VimEmulator), or

Change the Ctrl-X and Ctrl-V keys in File > Settings

under: Editor > Vim Emulation:
[image]

Change the column on the right from "Vim" to "IDE".

Comment: This works but unfortunately some of the shortcuts aren't listed here. I'm trying to use the `ctrl + up` and `ctrl + down` to navigate to next/previous method but I can't find this in the available list.

Comment: As of version 2018.3.3 "Vim Emulation" is listed under Editor instead of "Other Settings".

Answer (score 7):

If you wanna use vim and also shortcuts like Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V/Ctrl+X, you may redefine the shortcuts as IDE shortcuts in:

File-->Settings-->Other Settings-->Vim Emulator