# IntelliJ Double Click on Word Issue

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Whenever I double click on words in IntelliJ, the editor highlights the word like I am expecting it to, and it also acts as if I am pressing the insert button to do Overtyping. If the word is selected and I move down via keypad, it starts to highlight everything from the end of the word and it is very infuriating. How can I disable this? I looked through the settings and I am not seeing anything that is related to double clicking and highlighted words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, there was a plugin that was installed along with the installation that is IdeaVim. After uninstalling that and I do not have the issue anymore

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue, and the IdeaVim is not installed

Comment: Thanks you for the answer.I found this which describes they way of doing it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156011/how-to-change-editor-behavior-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Confirmed still works as of version 2019.2 IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate